# Remove X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID and X-ORACLE-DMS-RID response headers

Tags: weblogic12c

I have some JAX-RS services deployed in WebLogic 12.2.1. When any service send a response, WebLogic will add the following response headers:

```
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID
X-ORACLE-DMS-RID
```

How do I remove these two response headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the following JVM properties :
-Doracle.dms.context=OFF
-Dweblogic.diagnostics.context.DisableDMSHTTPAlways=true
But, removing these headers is not supported by Oracle when using FusionMiddleware because some OFMW components should not work properly any longer.

Comment: Thanks, I tested it out in our UAT server and it works. The two response headers no longer appear. But what puzzles me is that on our SIT server, we don't even have these two properties set, and yet the two response headers never appear.